# how to install flake8 in atom on windows

Tags: python, package, atom-editor, flake8

I have follow, these steps, but

"apm install linter
Next, we’re going to install a Python Linter package, to help us detect errors in our Python code.

This package is called linter-flake8 and it’s an interface to flake8. To install it, you need to run:

pip install flake8

pip install flake8-docstrings

apm install linter-flake8

You must restart Atom to see the changes"

I have followed those steps and every package with PIP and APM were installed, however, corrections are not made on my python code in ATOM. Is there something else i need to configure or to do appart from steps i mentioned?

2
3

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Environment Variable paths, especially if you have two concurrent versions of Python installed. Check to see which one is at the top of the list and ahead of the one your not currently developing within.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you an example of my installation

Installation path of python in my computer is

```
C:\Python36-32
```

So in control panel in system settings in advanced settings in path i add the following paths

```
C:\Python36-32
C:\Python36-32\Scripts
```

Now i reopen the cmd and i enter python if it worked you will see the python interpreter line.

To install flake8 system wide run the command

```
pip install flake8
```

In atom editor install  the package linter-flake8.When package is installed in settings of package in package path add the full path of package for example in my configuration i have in path

```
C:\Python36-32\Scripts\flake8   without the .exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got installed flake8 on `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3X\Scripts` just like me. If that is the case you only need to add that location to the PATH.